# I created pods using objects in kubernetes but the pods have status "Pending"

Tags: kubernetes

I created pods using `kubectl create -f file.yaml`. Deployment successfully gets created but the status of the pods show **Pending**. I also have docker image available on my local repository for which I am creating the pod. I am not sure what the issue is.

The yaml file is as follows.

[image: yaml file]

Kubernetes version that I am running is 1.1.6.

Comment: Please tell us the output of: `kubectl describe pod nginx-deployment` as per the answers below.

Comment: @iamnat I guess I got the error. This is the warning I got -Warning  FailedScheduling  20s (x22 over 5m)  default-scheduler  No nodes are available that match all of the predicates: NodeUnderDiskPressure (1). Where in I have to specify the node and can't it spawn one if not specified?

Answer (score 0):

Just from that information I cannot deduce what is wrong. What I can write is how to help you address such issues.

`kubectl describe pod __name_of_your_pod__
kubectl describe delpoyment nginx_deployment`

What I think has happend you might have no cpu resources, no nodes or taints.

BTW 1.1.6 k8s is pretty old. Think about an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to get the pods

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

to find more info, run:

```
kubectl describe po <you-pod-name>
```

you should be able to get more info from that output. Mostly
1) image is still pulled
2) resources crunch or docker not running

but the error/info message should take you forward.

Comment: I guess I got the error. This is the warning I got -Warning FailedScheduling 20s (x22 over 5m) default-scheduler No nodes are available that match all of the predicates: NodeUnderDiskPressure (1). Where in I have to specify the node and can't it spawn one if not specified?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get more info from the pod logs. For example ...

```
kubectl logs --tail=100 nginx-deployment
```

More information in the [kubectl docs](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_logs/)

Alternatively, you can open a console session, and troubleshoot from within the container itself.

```
kubectl get pods   # To get actual pod name
kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME>
```

Another thing you can try is running your container outside of Kubernetes(using `docker run -p 80:80 nginx-deployment`) just to ensure that your app is running correctly, and responding etc.

You can also try running `kubectl describe nodes`. This might give you more info to troubleshoot with.

Comment: I guess I got the error. This is the warning I got -Warning FailedScheduling 20s (x22 over 5m) default-scheduler No nodes are available that match all of the predicates: NodeUnderDiskPressure (1). Where in I have to specify the node and can't it spawn one if not specified?

Comment: Sounds like you have some resource issues, or installation issues potentially. Try running `kubectl describe nodes`. This might pinpoint your problem.

Comment: "Warning  ImageGCFailed         2m (x179 over 1d)    kubelet, 127.0.0.1  (combined from similar events): wanted to free 21701052825 bytes, but freed 0 bytes space with errors in image deletion: [rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete eff0bf8ede91 (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container 806316dc1e38" This is the error I got. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Try running `docker kill 806316dc1e38`, then run `docker rmi eff0bf8ede91 --force`, then restart your k8s cluster.